# Problem With Production Account and test API Paypal

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a problem. I use JS via SDK for payment, but I'm a site that requires a customer to pay, and then Refund a transaction for another customer, so I use a REST API. The problem is that the API is not working in my 'SandBox' account, so I switched my account to 'production'. The problem here seems to be that I cannot run my experiments Refunds transaction recovery, because your demo accounts are not running in "production".

testing by SandBox Accounts And Try Testing account Production

Comment: Use a different sandbox account / app.  https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/accounts , https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/sandbox

Comment: According to PayPal, the REST API is not possible in the sandbox and the account must be converted to a business account But the production account I tried to do experimental operations with the experimental tendency, but it fails because the account is not my reality.

Comment: Create as many accounts as you need. The receiving account must be a sandbox business account. Any production account is irrelevant to processing in sandbox.

Comment: i thing you not understand me. See, a Sandbox account cannot be used in production for testing.

 I need to use API REST Refund of a transaction, so I normally use Sandbox for testing but Paypal doesn't support API REST recovery in sandbox, so I switch my account to production but now I can't do my testing!!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by recovery. But, do your testing in sandbox mode.

Comment: @PrestonPHX i mean 'API REST recovery' => APP Refund money, it does not work in sandbox mode

Comment: No idea what API REST recovery is, and APP Refund money is also a strange phrase. API Refund operations work in sandbox.